# How to get request.subdomain in sass file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass

I want to get the current subdomain in .sass.erb file.

I have tried as follows -
$get_subdomain: <%= request.subdomain %>

But getting the error - undefined method or variable request.

I have also tried by adding custom function in lib but still getting the same error.
How to fetch the current subdomain in sass file? Can someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

SASS is compiled to CSS outside of the application context, so there is no request.

What's your problem around this? Why do you need the subdomain in SASS?

You may also have a look at asset_url/_host configuration for SASS and/or Rails.